# How to write the code after the comma within this "groupingBy" in java8?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `Student` class:

```
public class Student{
    private String name;
    private Map<String,Reward> rewards=new HashMap<>();
//stores the rewards that the student got,key is reward's name.
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int countRewards(){//just counts the #of rewards
        return this.rewards.size();
    } 
}
```

And the `School` Class:

```
public class School{
    private Map<String,Student> students=new TreeMap<>();
//Stores the students in the school,key is student's name.

    public List<String> countingRewardsPerStudent(){
        Map <String,Integer>step1= 
             this.students.values().stream()
            .sorted(comparing(Student::countRewards).reversed().thenComparing(Student::getName))
            .collect(groupingBy((Student s)->s.getName(),     //Error
                                (Student s)->s.countRewards() //here !!!!!
                     ));

        return step1.entrySet().stream().map(s->s.getKey()+" has rewards:"+s.getValue())
                .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

The method `countingRewardsPerStudent` needs to return a `List<String>` which contains student's name and number of rewards for the student as in `Name has rewards:###`.

I'm OK with the `return` line, but I am stuck with the `groupingBy((Student s)->s.getName(),XXXX)`, I've tried so many ways to perform `XXXX`, but it was not good. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Posting half baked code and then asking us to fix it for you. Not fair!. Atleast post all relevant code and the code you used test whatever is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to decide what to do if two students have the same name - assuming you want to add their rewards, it could look like:

```
.collect(groupingBy(Student::getName, summingInt(Student::countRewards)));
```

If you don't have more than one student with a given name you could do :

```
.collect(toMap(Student::getName, Student::countRewards));
```